# A mongo DB query with a MAX(DATE)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Hello I have a BD with many fields where an user can enter many times, I need to create a query where I can Group by user and bring me the last entry date in the system, but other additional data such as  previous  and the ID of the transaction, the date is createdAT, it brings me the date but not the last one ... here the code:

```
db.getCollection("usersos").aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$group" : { 
                "_id" : { 
                    "_id" : "$_id", 
                    "user" : "$user", 
                    "previo" : "$previo"
                }, 
                "MAX(createdAt)" : { 
                    "$max" : "$createdAt"
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$project" : { 
                "user" : "$_id.user", 
                "MAX(createdAt)" : "$MAX(createdAt)", 
                "_id" : "$_id._id", 
                "previo" : "$_id.previo"
            }
        }
    ]
);
```

Im staring in nosql, some help thank.....and excuseme the mstake....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grouping by `$_id` will mean that every input document is a separate group, i.e. no grouping will really happen.

You could try pre-sorting by `createdAt`, which might be helped by an index on that field, then the group can select `$first` to get the first entry for each field that you care about.

```
db.usersos.aggregate([
    {$sort: {createdAt: -1}},
    {$group: {
          _id:"$user",
          docId: {$first: "$_id"},
          previo: {$first: "$previo"},
          createdAt: {$first: "$createdAt"}
    }},
    { $project: { 
        user: "$_id",
        _id: "$docId",
        previo: 1,
        createdAt: 1
    }}
])
```

Comment: Joe thank dear friend, its works!!!!! you have a lot knowledge in Nosql Thank again!!!!